# Exchanging documents among several system and printing them

Tags: delphi, pdf, delphi-7, gdi

There are two systems. I need to get the document in some format and print it in my application.
The source file should be in a pdf format.

1. Do you know the component for delphi7 that i could be able to open pdf file and print it on delphi's canvas. Is such approach good for the pdf document quality?
2. Or which format of the source document could be better to print in delphi application?

Thanks

Comment: Print is on paper. If you want to render it onto canvas - then why ? Do you want to display PDF preview in your form ? Or just print the PDF ? or embed PDF into your own report document and print the composing document ? 
http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=delphi+pdf http://www.torry.net/quicksearchd.php?String=pdf&Title=Yes

Comment: I only need to embed that document in my print report.

Comment: you cannot print your report, then print PDF after that, starting with next paper sheet ?

Comment: I was only asking how can I embed the pdf inside my report. I have an array of canvases on which I draw the content. I would like to be able to ambed pdf on one of them..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think almost all PDF preview components may do it.

When searching - https://www.google.ru/search?client=opera&q=delphi+render+pdf+to+canvas&sourceid=opera - you would instantly get at least few commercial libs:

- http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=229&t=Convert_PDF_To_High-Resolution_Images_Using_Delphi
- http://www.quickpdflibrary.com/faq/can-i-use-quick-pdf-as-a-viewer-in-my-delphi-application.php
- http://www.wpcubed.com/manuals/wpviewpdf/idh_twpviewpdf_printhdc.htm

*TCanvas is a wapper around Windows HDC. See http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Graphics.TCanvas.Handle*